# Trace of $3x^2+6y^2=1$

Tags: trace, plane-geometry

Let $$ be the surface defined by the equation $3^2+6^2=1$.

Determine the range of values of $x$ for which the $x$-traces (cross-sections) are non-empty. That is, find all $$ such that the system of equations $3^2+6^2=1,\,=a$ has a solution. In addition, choose the correct general description for the traces from the list.

Repeat for the $$- and $z$-traces.
The $$ traces are (lines, ellipses, hyperbolas, parabolas?) and are non-empty for $y$ in the range:

Comment: There is no $x$ in the equation, solutions are independent of the value of $x$?

Comment: the trace are just lines from (-infinity,infinity) but what about y and z